# When the DEA says a drug is X times more potent than another, what do they mean?

Tags: measurement, psychopharmacology

[E.g.](https://www.dea.gov/factsheets/fentanyl)

> Fentanyl is a synthetic opioid that is 80-100 times stronger than morphine.

What does that refer to?

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potency_(pharmacology):

> The IUPHAR has stated that 'potency' is "an imprecise term that should always be further defined", for instance as EC50, IC50, ED50, LD50 and so on.

I guess [effective dose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_dose_(pharmacology)) is the relevant notion here, but which version does the DEA use ED50, ED95 (does it matter which)?

Presumably they are not talking about [receptor affinity](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0197734) which would be mostly irrelevant from DEA's perspective (although the FDA suggests otherwise). The latter ratio between fentanyl and morphine is only 1.35 to 1.14 on the μ-opioid receptor. Even that is not really a good way to compare, because actual measurements of affinity have a large margin of error:

[image]

Comment: Apparently the CDC itself [has been criticized](https://www.medpagetoday.com/painmanagement/painmanagement/50722) for making weaker/stronger-than-morphine comparisons. But let's take one claim at a time.

Answer (score 2):

At least the 100 number seems based on the CDC [parenteral dose conversion](https://www.mdanderson.org/documents/for-physicians/algorithms/clinical-management/clin-management-post-op-pain-web-algorithm.pdf):

[image]

(Fentanyl has poor oral bioavailability, so it's not intended to be used that way.)